# Calculate percentage from values in a string using SQL

Tags: sql, regex

I'm not entirely sure I worded the title properly:

I have a column with progress status

```
| progress|
| -------- |
|10 of 100 completed|
|20 of 100 completed|
|40 of 200 completed|
|69 of 420 completed|
etc
```

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to calculate the percentage of each row in 1 line? Or do I have to separate the values out with regex to 2 columns and calculate it that way?

I was thinking something like (I'm going to butcher this I apologize, I don't actually know how to write SQL):

```
regexep (r'^[0-9]+) / regexp (r'[0-9]$)
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `r'[0-9]$'` won't work for the second number, since it's not at the end of the string.

Comment: You're missing closing quotes for your regexp.

Comment: In MySQL you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract a delimited string.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Redshift, ???

Comment: Consider ````([0-9]+(?=\s+of))```` (or ````^([0-9]+(?=\s+of)````) and ````((?<=of\s)[0-9]+)````. Loot at https://regex101.com/r/qlwlC2/1

Comment: Google SQL, sorry I didn't see a tag for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0+, you can use [regexp_substr()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) to get the result in one line.

Here is the [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gYb8D4P3Q7uUBoLCixBCV8/0):

```
select
    task,
    CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(progress, '\d+', 1, 1) AS float) / CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(progress, '\d+', 1, 2) AS float) as progress_rate
from
    task
```

| task | progress_rate |
| --- | --- |
| `("10 of 100 completed")` | `0.1` |
| `("20 of 100 completed")` | `0.2` |
| `("40 of 200 completed")` | `0.2` |
| `("69 of 420 completed")` | `0.16428571428571428` |

Comment: This brought me 99% there. I'm using Google SQL, \d doesn't work I subbed it with r' [0-9]+' and it worked! Thank you